# Manual of Resident Evil 4 Greatest Hits version for PS2 is too large for the case

Tags: sony-playstation, case

I just bought a used copy of RE4 for PS2 and saw that the Greatest Hits version of the manual was all wrinkled. I improved it by putting it under a pile of heavy books for a couple days just to realize that it was too large for the case which was the cause of the wrinkles.

I am very interested to know how can this even happen. It is not like the designer of the booklet back then was not aware of the width of the case. Does anyone have the same problem with other PS2 Greatest Hits games?

**Wrinkles:**

[image]

**Booklet in case:**

[image]

**Size comparison between regular booklet and GH booklet:**

[image]

**Close-up of the edge of the booklet in the case hinge:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

So yes, [mnem's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27526) is spot on. This booklet was never meant to be put inside the case but shrink-wrapped at the back of it to provide the French Canadian translation.

**Back of the GH booklet with back of the case:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the original case?  You could imagine something like the previous owner accidentally stepped on the original case and broke it, so they put the inserts into some other cover they happened to have on hand, which might not have been the same size.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was wondering the same thing and tried the other official single-disc case variant (no memory card holder) from a more recent game with the same result.

Comment: Root Cause Analysis: someone screwed up.  What more explanation is needed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That looks like it might be the French Canadian version of the manual, maybe? If it is that could explain it. For thicker manuals where both versions wouldn't fit inside the case the French version would typically be shrink-wrapped to the back of the case and it would be a bit wider so that it covered the entire back instead of seeing the edge of the slipcover on both sides. I'm not sure why they made them that way but it's definitely something I've encountered before. You'll know for sure if it has a bilingual copy of the rear slip cover art printed on the outside back page of the manual.

Comment: Yes, that's the French Canadian version. I updated the question for the sake of completeness. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Wild guess [having worked in design] a simple communications error…

No-one told the designer that the case would have clips. They just gave them a case size, or even just a size, no real indication as to what it would be used in.
The booklet is designed to just fit the case.

One further degree of remote… they could have been given only the size of the outside of the case, so it won't even fit loose.

Comment: Sounds like a typical, mundane real world issue :))

Comment: I'd vote for it being dimensioned to the outside of the case, and originally being sold shrinkwrapped. Having worked in technical writing, issues like "it won't fit" (not to mention "wrong type of binder", "colours don't match" etc.) are well beyond the comprehension of most marketroids.

Comment: That could definitely have happened! I do hope the designers have access to templates though or at least actual useful specs.

Comment: Well, the other answer knew there was a version that was never meant to go inside the case - solves the mystery ;)